# How to use a trigger to only insert one row

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am doing a third year project using an intel galileo that reads an RFID card, and signs a student into a class, and I am using multiple tables.

I have nearly completed it as all reads are been recorded into a table called read_log. What I want to achieve is when a record is entered into this read_log, set a trigger to just insert the card number, which again is been sent this table read_log.

So what i have so far is :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `test` AFTER UPDATE ON `readlog` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT into attendence(S_no) 

SELECT s.Stu_no from student s 
JOIN readLog r ON s.Stu_no=r.Cardid WHERE s.Stu_no=r.Cardid; 

END
```

I can confirm the trigger is working, as once i scan the rfid card over the galileo it inserts into the database, and the trigger triggers but enters the number 29 times, so there is 29 records entered everytime i read.

Can someone provide a tip as to what to look for or how to go about writing a trigger that will only insert one row. I have tried update instead of insert but this does nothing.

Comment: Have you checked to see what your select statement returns when it's run by itself(not in the trigger)?

Comment: You could simply `ON s.Stu_no=r.Cardid WHERE s.Stu_no=r.Cardid` erasing the `where` clause. 
What are the primary key of table `attendence`? Could you show the output of `show create table attendence`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `INSERT`, use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

The former (`IGNORE`) checks `UNIQUE` key(s) to avoid inserting a second time.  The latter (IODKU) will either insert a new row or update an existing row (based on any `UNIQUE` key(s)).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for ll your help, it gave me alot of ideas to try. As i only wanted it to concentrate on the last entry from read_log I took WHERE s.Stu_no=r.Cardid and changed it to WHERE s.Stu_no=(SELECT MAX(id) from read_log) and it now only concentrates on the last entry in read_log.

cheers for the helps lads

Comment: Try to update your question, instead answering it to thank people.